# VBA DateAdd not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the DateTime.DateAdd VBA function in Excel to create a column of dates. Using the code below, the day does not change as expected when the time progresses to midnight.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1) = "DateTime"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Day"

        currentDate = CDate("10/3/2016 11:59:30 PM")

        For i = 1 To 10
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = currentDate
            .Cells(i + 1, 2) = DateTime.Day(currentDate)
            currentDate = DateTime.DateAdd("s", 5, currentDate)
        Next i

        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub
```

Output:

- DateTime | Day
- 10/3/2016 11:59:30 PM | 3
- 10/3/2016 11:59:35 PM | 3
- 10/3/2016 11:59:40 PM | 3
- 10/3/2016 11:59:45 PM | 3
- 10/3/2016 11:59:50 PM | 3
- 10/3/2016 11:59:55 PM | 3
- 10/**3**/2016 12:00:00 AM | **4**  *(day values do not match!)*
- 10/4/2016 12:00:05 AM | 4
- 10/4/2016 12:00:10 AM | 4
- 10/4/2016 12:00:15 AM | 4

Changing the number format to military time gives a similar result. If I use the output dates as the x-values for a chart, the chart will use the 'incorrect' day value. However, the day changes as expected if I change the start time in the code to 10/3/2016 11:59:45 PM. Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternate more stable way to add time to a Date in VBA?

EDIT:

Excellent workarounds provided by mrbungle and Comintern.  They both achieve the same end result but I like mrbungle's method just a hair better because it avoids altering the value, albeit a negligible amount.

To summarize the alternatives:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1) = "DateTime"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Day"

        currentDate = CDate("10/3/2016 11:59:30 PM")

        For i = 1 To 10
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = CStr(currentDate) ' mrbungle's method
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = currentDate + 0.000000001 ' Comintern's method
            .Cells(i + 1, 2) = DateTime.Day(currentDate)
            currentDate = DateTime.DateAdd("s", 5, currentDate)
        Next i

        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this qualifies as an answer but it does get around the problem.  It seems pasting the date as `String` get's around the issue.  And searching around it seems this is a problem with Excel adding dates and moving days.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim currentDate2 As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Cells.Clear
    .Cells(1, 1) = "DateTime"
    .Cells(1, 2) = "Day"

    currentDate = CDate("10/3/2016 11:59:30 PM")
    currentDate2 = currentDate
    For i = 1 To 10
        .Cells(i + 1, 1) = currentDate2
        .Cells(i + 1, 2) = Day(currentDate)
        '.Cells(i + 1, 3) = test
        currentDate = DateTime.DateAdd("s", 5, currentDate)
        currentDate2 = currentDate
    Next i

    .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be an Excel formatting bug.  In fact, the VBA values are correct:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentDate As Date
    currentDate = CDate("10/3/2016 11:59:30 PM")
    For i = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print currentDate, Day(currentDate)
        currentDate = DateTime.DateAdd("s", 5, currentDate)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

> ```
> 10/3/2016 11:59:30 PM        3 
> 10/3/2016 11:59:35 PM        3 
> 10/3/2016 11:59:40 PM        3 
> 10/3/2016 11:59:45 PM        3 
> 10/3/2016 11:59:50 PM        3 
> 10/3/2016 11:59:55 PM        3 
> 10/4/2016      4 
> 10/4/2016 12:00:05 AM        4 
> 10/4/2016 12:00:10 AM        4 
> 10/4/2016 12:00:15 AM        4
> ```

The moral seems to be that if you're doing date arithmetic in Excel and have to correctly represent midnight, you should add a tiny delta as a workaround:

```
 currentDate = CDate("10/3/2016 11:59:30 PM") + 0.00000000001
```

This "tricks" Excel into using the correct date for 12:00 AM.